# python regex to extract string from log file line

Tags: python-2.7

I want to extract the data from log file

For opening the file:

```
a = open('access.log','rb')
lines = a.readlines()
```

So suppose line[0]:

```
123.456.678.89 - - [04/Aug/2014:12:01:41 +0530] "GET /123456789_10.10.20.111 HTTP/1.1" 404 537 "-" "Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)"
```

I want to extract only 123456789 and 10.10.20.111 from "GET /123456789_10.10.20.111 HTTP/1.1"

The pattern will be like string starts with /, repetition of digit then underscore then ip.

I tried this, and it works. I think it takes overhead

```
node = re.search(r'\"(.*)\"', line).group(1)
node = node.split(" ")[1]
node,ip = node.split("_")
node = node[1:]
print node,ip
```

How to get this with pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to do this in one line?

```
nodeip = re.search(r'([\d]{9})_([\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3})', line)
```

Now your node and IP in groups 1 and 2:

```
print nodeip.group(1), nodeip.group(2)
```

Outputs:

```
123456789 10.10.20.111
```

Comment: Ok, but `[0-9]` means that you need only one numeric char (equals to `[0-9]{1}`). Use `[0-9]+` (equals to `[0-9]{1,}`) for non-fixed length.

Comment: hey @doubleui your solution work for me..
im going to extract date from above log so i used time_string = re.search(r'\[(.*)\]', line) it works for me but i created separate search,if i want to get it as third group in above query ..??

Comment: `([\d]{2}/[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}/[\d]{4}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2} \+[\d]{4})(?:.+?)([\d]{1,})_([\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3}\.[\d]{1,3})`

Comment: `(?:.+?)` means: `( group_start` `?: do_not_store_to_group` `.+ any_chars` `? but_lazy_untill_found_next_rule_or_without_it_will_store_all_chars_untill_end` `) group_end`. In other words: skip any chars like `] "GET /` with lazy method.

Comment: You can replace `[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}` with `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)`.

Comment: this book was really helpfull for me few years ago
[O'Reilly Regular Expression Pocket Reference](http://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expression-Pocket-Reference-Expressions/dp/0596514271/ref=pd_sim_b_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=1379R3ASPVXM0C3BHXJP)